# Update apache commons for readyAPI

Tags: soapui, apache-commons, ready-api

I need to upgrade apache commons for readyAPI , I have two solutions

- Leave the current version in the lib and put the new one in the ext : didn't work)
- Delete the current version in the lib and replace it with the new one : readyAPI freeze on loading jars from lib.

Is there a way to force readyAPI to use the version in the ext file and not the lib file ? If not is there any solutions to update my apache commons ?

Comment: Which Commons project do you need to update? Is there a particular feature you need to use?

Comment: Yes, TreeMap for POI (XSSF)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a separate Java or Groovy project that contains your dependencies (Commons, POI, ...), along with an interface to invoke the functions you need, and bundle all of that into a JAR, and then drop this JAR in the `ext` directory. After restarting soapUI, you should then be able to call the interface through a Groovy script.